# How to make GWT decouple component

Tags: java, gwt, components

I am looking for a way to make decoupled GWT component. So that I can integrate it in other different GWT component or projects.

For example:
I am having a custom GWT Tree widget (own css )and now I want to use this Tree widget in other `GWT` applications by just adding .jar in the project.

What are the best way to do it?

Comment: Best way to structure the Java code, or best way to go about packaging a module JAR?

Answer (score 1):

Writing a reusable GWT library (JAR) is a little more involved than just inheriting the module, because your high-level project (using that library) needs to have access to the class source, not compiled code.

Whether to create the actual utility "module" (to inherit) is up to you. GWT doesn't require that. I only define modules at the top level. My utility JARs are just collections of classes, like they would be in normal Java w/o GWT.

1. Move that code: Java classes, images, and other resources into a separate project/module, that'd build a separate JAR.
2. Put this in your library JAR Maven file:

   ```
   <build>
       <resources>
           <resource>
               <directory>src/main/java</directory>
               <includes>
                   <include>x.y.z/**/*.java</include>
               </includes>
           </resource>
       </resources>
   ```

Don't forget to include images and other resources if you have them - not just "*.java". Keep in mind that if you are distributing that module, that's your source files, so be as restrictive, as possible and don't include non-GWT stuff.

3. Include that JAR in your main project's Maven dependencies. That's it. No messing with GWT modules.
4. EDIT: make sure you use the same package structure in your utility JAR, as in your main (consuming) GWT project. Or add those packages to the module declaration.

Your Maven GWT plugin should remain in the main module, not utility JAR.

Answer (score 0):

This will vary based on the requirement like If you are using Maven then

- Create a maven project follow the gwt packing structure and create all your custom widget or component
- Create the main project and add the dependency of the above project to this project and re used the Custom Component(Tree Widget).

If you are not using Maven then normal gwt application then

- Create Dynamic Web application  follow the gwt packing structure and create all your custom widget,which is in result .jar project
- Create you main project and Go to Java build path, Add External JARS(add the above project .jar as external JARS) to this.

Hope this solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

You can create your component as an independent gwt module, then you can export it as a jar file and use it easily in any other gwt project.
There are many many samples like this available on the net.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your GWT module containig common widgets into a separate jar and reuse this jar where you need it.

I suggest you this maven plugin

http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/

it helps you to create GWT modules in conjunction with maven

Maven is one of the best way to handle projects dependencies in java.

Once your jar is created you can include this jar in the classpath of the project where you need it.

In order to use widgets of an external GWT module you must also declare gwt dependency from this module putting

```
<inherits name="gwtXmlPackageOfYourExternalModule.YourModuleName"/>
```

inside the .gwt.xml of your project